# String Formatting in python remove whitespace before : in most inefficient way

Tags: python, string

I want to get this output. 
AssertionError: a mystery exception!
However I get this output
AssertionError : a mystery exception!
I want to remove the space before ":" what is the best way to do so.
Thank you very much

```
def fonction(n):
    try:
        print(mystery(n))
    except Exception as err:
        print(type(err).__name__,":",err)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the string formatting operator:

```
print('%s: %s' % (type(err).__name__, err))
```

or the `str.format` method:

```
print('{}: {}'.format(type(err).__name__, err))
```

Comment: .format is the [newer and preferred style](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/) of string formatting.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using python3.6 you can format string this way as well:

```
print(f'{type(err).__name__}: {err}')
```

This is called f-string and is a new way of formatting strings.